# ¿Como puedo leer una llave que esta formada por id _ nombre en javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, objeto

Intento leer una variable de un json. Pero esta variable tiene la siguiente sintaxis.

```
"id_nombre":{
Variables,
}
```

viendo un ejemplo seria:

```
0_seccion:{
variables
}
```

Mi problema es que no se como tengo que acceder a este json. ya intente con:

```
objeto.id_nombre
objeto.'id_nombre'
objeto['id_nombre]
```

Pero en todas falla.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como tengo regresa el json. Debe de tener este formato dado que el id identifica la sección y nombre el componente. Y de no seguirse esta nomenclatura puede haber un componente con el mismo nombre.

Lo que quiero hacer es:

```
var otra = variable.0-MenuComponent;
```

Comment: Recuerda "editar" tu pregunta para agregar más información, revisa la información sugerida para crear preguntas [ask]. El usuario Francisco te solicita "Puedes poner un ejemplo mas completo para ayudarte un poco mas? Ahora mismo hay pocos datos para poder saber donde esta el problema.  No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio.
Recuerda poner las llaves antes { _id:"0" }"

Answer (score 1):

El primero no es válido porque no se puede almacenar un objeto en un `string`, de todas formas estas creando un diccionario y no estas asignando un valor a a clave.

No válido:

```
"id_nombre":{
    Variables,
}
```

Válido:

```js
var id_nombre = {
  variable1:" algo",
  "nombre":" otro",
}
alert(id_nombre.variable1);
alert(id_nombre["nombre"]);
```

Y el segundo ejemplo no es válido ya que una variable no debería empezar por un número.

Comment: No tengo problemas guardando los json, tengo problemas intentando leerlos.

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como tengo regresa el json. Debe de tener este formato dado que el id identifica la sección y nombre el componente. Y de no seguirse esta nomenclatura puede haber un componente con el mismo nombre.

Lo que quiero hacer es:

```
var otra = variable.0-MenuComponent;
```

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo mas completo para ayudarte un poco mas? Ahora mismo hay pocos datos para poder saber donde esta el problema

Comment: Recuerda poner las llaves antes { _id:"0" }

Comment: si quieres añadir algo a la pregunta edítala, no crees una respuesta para eso

Answer (score 1):

Los nombres de nodos pueden ser àlfanumericos.

`variable.some`, `variable.algoLocochon10`

Cuando se necesitan caracteres como "-" y mezclarlo con variables.

`variable['nombre-con-guion']`

O si quieres

```
var numero = 0;

variable[numero + '-nombre'];
```

Si utilizas la version ES6

```
var numero = 1;

variable[`${numero}-nombre`]
```